# Accessing USB Pendrive from android tablet

Tags: android, usb

We have a usb port in our android tablet(version 4.0.3).

1. How do we find out any PenDrive connected on that port or not.
2. How do we access the files in the USB Pendrive which connected on that port through programmatically in android.

We have a `/mnt` contained Folder as

`asec`
`extsd`
`obb`
`sdcard`
`secure`
`usbhost1`

1. How to programmatically identify which one is `Internal Memory Path`, `External SD Card Path` and `USB Path`.
2. What is the purpose for used this folder `asec`, `obb` and `secure`.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Bala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess to use the external sdcard you need to use this:

```
new File("/mnt/external_sd/")
```

OR

```
new File("/mnt/extSdCard/")
```

OR

```
new File("/mnt/usb_storage")
```

in replace of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Works for me. You should check whats in the directory mnt first and work from there..

You should use some type of selection method to choose which sdcard to use:

```
File storageDir = new File("/mnt/");
if(storageDir.isDirectory()){
    String[] dirList = storageDir.list();
    //TODO some type of selecton method?
}
```

The "pen drive" is located in /mnt/ (just like all other storage devices in 4.0>)

It will probably be different for some devices, for the Acer Iconia A500 running 4.0.3 usb storage is under `/mnt/usb_storage/`

Comment: I think for now (I don't see any advancements in 4.1) you have to choose it yourself. I dont believe there is a api for this yet. I can see it coming soon tho. I should raise this to Android dev.

Comment: what about 5.1?  i am not getting any PATh for USB mounted?

Comment: i m Getting Permission Error While Accessing USB Which Permission i need to apply in menifest

Answer (score 1):

> How do we find out any PenDrive connected on that port or not.

There is no documented and supported means to do that in the Android SDK. You would need to speak with your device manufacturer and get their recommendations for how to do this for their specific device.

> How do we access the files in the USB Pendrive which connected on that port through programmatically in android.

See above.

Comment: Yes there is no "supported means" but there is a way :D

Comment: @SmartLemon: Except that there is no guarantee that they will mount it under `/mnt`, no guarantee whether it will be mounted read-only or read-write, etc. And the rules will vary by device manufacturer, even by firmware version.

Comment: Thats why you check whether mnt is a directory.

Comment: is there any way to find the path for android external devise path like pendrive and any thing

Answer (score 0):

****Using this you can find path and asses the file in USB****

```
public String getStoragepath() {

        try {

            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = runtime.exec("mount");
            InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            String line;
            String[] patharray = new String[10];
            int i = 0;
            int available = 0;

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String mount = new String();
                if (line.contains("secure"))
                    continue;
                if (line.contains("asec"))
                    continue;

                if (line.contains("fat")) {// TF card
                    String columns[] = line.split(" ");
                    if (columns != null && columns.length > 1) {
                        mount = mount.concat(columns[1] + "/requiredfiles");

                        patharray[i] = mount;
                        i++;

                        // check directory is exist or not
                        File dir = new File(mount);
                        if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
                            // do something here

//                          t1.show();
                            available = 1;
                            finalpath = mount;
                            break;
                        } else {


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (available == 1) {


            } else if (available == 0) {

                finalpath = patharray[0];

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return finalpath;
    }
```

Comment: is it for USB via OTG ?